# Is it possible to import more than one sqlite3 files from terminal?

Tags: sqlite

I have two databases that I would like to use in sqlite. They are both in the same folder in terminal. I can import one by the command below.

```
$sqlite3 first.sqlite3
```

And it jumps to 
    `sqlite>`
where I can see the table 'first' and its content.

However, I also would like to import the second database into sqlite. I try

```
sqlite> .import second.sqlite3 second
sqlite> pragma table_info(second);
```

It shows

```
0|SQLite format 3|TEXT|0||0
```

, but does not give me the table.

When I use

```
sqlite> select * from second;
```

, it shows

```
  col1 text,      
  col2 text,
  col3 text,
  col4 text
)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [attach database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_attach_database.htm):

```
sqlite3 first.sqlite3
attach 'second.sqlite3' as second;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I obtained after attaching the database. Is there any other way to do this? Thank you. `sqlite> pragma table_info(program);
0|SQLite format 3|TEXT|0||0
sqlite> select * from program;
  id text,      
  programID text,
  orchestra text,
  season text
)
SQLite format 3
  id text,      
  programID text,
  orchestra text,
  season text
)`

Comment: program is your database name or table name? try command `.tables` after attaching db to see your table fullname

Comment: After attaching, `sqlite> .tables` returns `program          program.program  work`, in which `work` is the first table and `program` is the second. I don't know what `program.program` is for. I used `attach 'program.sqlite3' as program;`

Comment: `program.program` is table from attached database. So after attaching databases you can access its tables by `DB_ALIAS.TABLE_NAME`

Comment: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/bug-quot-PRAGMA-table-info-quot-td62584.html @Hsun-YiHsieh try `pragma program.table_info(program)` It worked on sqlite3, windows